# X11: mirror input to multiple windows

Tags: x11, keyboard-event

There is a nice tool called [`xlax`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/xlax/xlax.1.en.html) which allows keyboard input to be mirrored to multiple X11 windows. One problem that I encountered during the use of this tool is that the two windows can desynchronize if they respond to the input at different rates (I am using it to cycle through correlated image sequences in two separate image viewer instances; one of the instances has larger images and responds to the input more slowly, and thus desynchronizes from the one with smaller images). I am wondering whether there would be a simple way to prevent this desychronization.

Comment: If the image viewer drops events when it was too slow, I don't see an easy way except increasing delay between keypresses.

Comment: @dirkt: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.